# A graph with two types of vertices, but edges exists between the two types.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I have recently been exploring graph theory and structures.
And I was wondering if there is a term in graph such that `G = (U,V,E)`
where `U` and `V` and two types of vertices and there can be edges of type `uv`, `uu` and `vv`.

I know it's not exactly a Bipartite graph because i want to be able to add an edges between same vertex types. In the first image linked, you can see that there are two types of nodes (represented by letters vs numbers). And you can also see that there can be an edge between nodes of the same types.
[Image of example of Graph in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdsPq.png)

Further question, would it be easier if I had a second condition of : Only directed edges can exists between same type vertices like in the second image
[Image of example graph with both directed and undirected eges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IESwV.png)

Comment: a non-properly colored graph?

Comment: @Asinomás I'm not super familiar with graph coloring but with the little that I do know,  I think that "non-properly colored" or "defective coloured graph" could be a term for what I'm describing.

Comment: But i'm not quite sure it decsibed the second scenraio.

Comment: For your second question, "a graph with both directed and undirected edges" seems very rare in math, and makes me suspect the best place for you to search would be in the field of the application(s) you have in mind.